# How to perform basic statistics on a csv file to explore my numeric and non-numeric variables with Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I've imported a csv file which is like this :

```
MR; IT;  UPI; CAE; IIL;                ED;   NS;                  DATE; DUIOD;NBOPP;
30;  0; null;   2;   0; bgpel:10PT-MIP   ; null; 2013-05-20 21:03:00.0;   300;null;
20;  0; null;   4;   1; bzrgfel:125TZ-ATR; null; 2013-04-01 19:50:02.0;   302;null; 
10;  2; null;   2;   0; bhtuyel:105MF-AXI; null; 2013-04-26 17:12:00.0;   298;null;
```

I'm new on Spark and I want to perform basic statistics like

- getting the min, max, mean, median and std of numeric variables
- getting the values frequencies for non-numeric variables.

My questions are :

- With what type of object is it better to work and how to import my csv into that type (RDD, DataFrame, ...)?
- How to do those basic statistics easily ?

I've tried with RDD but there is probably a better way to do :

```
val csv=sc.textFile("myFile.csv");  
val summary: MultivariateStatisticalSummary = Statistics.colStats(csv)
```

I get an error like:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
```

Comment: you have to parse your file to extract each column in separate RDD

Comment: @ka4eli Why would you do something like this?

Comment: @SparkUser Even if you processed your input correctly `Statistics.colStats` won't work in your case. It expects `RDD[Vector]` and `Vectrors` can store only doubles. What kind of statistics do you want to compute on categorical/ordinal variables?

Comment: So I need to extract only the numeric variables to do a colStats, but I do not know how to extract them.
For categorical variables I want to count frequences of the modalities, but I do not know which function in Spak can do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is one open source library available on github [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). you can use that for parsing and other transformation. And you can also convert your csv to dataframe directly using this code.

```
sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(Options).load();
```